# Can I override Django password form layout?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin, django-registration

I have overridden the Django login and [registration](https://django-registration.readthedocs.io) forms by creating the templates `registration/login.html`, `registration/logout.html`, `registration/registration_closed.html` and `registration/registration_form.html`.

However, the password change forms are in the original style. Unlike the existing forms, it doesn't look like django-registration.registration.auth_urls specifies HTML templates for these password forms. So how can I override them to look like my custom templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could override `registration/password_reset_form.html`. This resides inside the Django contrib.admin app. It's not related to the `django-registration` app.

There are other templates you would like to override too. Please have look in to the [Django GitHub repository](https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/registration).